# How do I determine the relationships between custom objects?

Tags: relationships

Sorry if this has been addressed before, but I could not find a thread that was asking this.

Background: I have limited OO programming experience in VB, Java, Python, etc. I am a Super User on Performance Edition and we do not appear to have Schema Builder. **I do not have admin rights**. I am working on a Document for my job where we will be "suggesting" a design for the Developers to either adopt or modify.

So I'm trying to figure out what the cardinality/ordinality of some custom objects is in SalesForce. In other databases that I've used, you can view the ERD model, but I'm not finding that functionality here.

How can I find out what the relationship between different custom objects is? I was thinking maybe just go to the different objects and see if there are master/detail &/or lookup relationships defined in existing fields, but am wondering if there's an easier way?

Thanks for any and all help, even if it's just referring me to existing documentation!! :)

Comment: Your org does have the schema builder, which is really the only place to see all of this information, but you need the "Customize Application" permission in your profile to see it. And unfortunately this permission gives you access to the ability to create and delete custom fields, etc and all that other admin stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the ability to view the setup pages for custom objects? If so, I believe you could speed this up slightly by downloading Eclipse with the Force.com IDE. Then, you could pull down the custom and standard objects for your instance, and do a search for master-detail and lookup fields. I'm not sure exactly what the search string would be, but the field types are in the xml, so just find one and use that as a search term.

Of course, your manual process might be faster if you have a small number of custom objects.

Comment: Matt, I do have the ability to view the setup pages for custom objects; I will look into your solution to speed things up.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Utilizing Workbench is a nice alternative to digging through setup or pulling info with the IDE.  https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: HomerJ, unfortunately I don't have the access to view the metadata there, either : /